# how to make discord bot give a random response when prompted?

Tags: python, discord, bots

basically title. i've made a very simple bot so far, like, it can answer 'hi' with a simple message like 'hello, {username!]' really easy stuff.
im very new to python, so i couldnt figure this out on my own, so if anyone has an answer i would appreciate it.

i wanted to make a kind of command where you would type in something, lets say for example; '!greeting' and the bot would respond with a random message of, say, 3 options. lets say they were 'hi, hello, howdy'

so if i said '!greeting' the bot would say 'hi!'
but if my friend typed the same thing, '!greeting', the bot might say 'howdy'

this might be easy but its too much for my small brain. if anyone needs to see my code so far or anything i can provide :D

Comment: Use the random module.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from random import randint

@client.command()
async def greeting(ctx):
    list = ["hi", "hello", "howdy"]
    await ctx.send(list[randint(0,2)])
```

Comment: '  @client.command
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it depends on your code, if you can provide I will try to solve